# How to apply antd dark theme for a React App?

Tags: reactjs, less, antd

I want to use this dark theme for my new react web app : https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-dark-theme

After following directions on customizing theme [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) and directions on applying the theme in README [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-dark-theme/blob/master/README.md) my config-overrides.js looks like this:

```
const { darkTheme } = require('@ant-design/dark-theme');
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports('import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
    style: true,
  }),
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    modifyVars: darkTheme
  }),
);
```

This does not seem to be working. For example, I have a Menu antd component still showing up in "light" theme instead of "dark" theme.

I would like to have all my antd components render with the dark theme without me explicitly setting it. Is that possible? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Not a frontend dev here, so please let me know if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was a combination of both @JoseFelix and @Anujs answers. Thank you both for the answers:

```
const darkTheme = require('@ant-design/dark-theme');
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports('import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
    style: true,
  }),
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    modifyVars: darkTheme.default
  }),
);
```

Comment: any idea how to enable toggling between dark and default theme within the app directly?

Comment: which file is that that I have to update?

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus its the config-overrides.js

Answer (score 2):

The code is destructuring the default export when the default export is the object with the variables. Therefore, it should be:

```
const darkTheme = require('@ant-design/dark-theme').default;
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports('import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
    style: true,
  }),
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    modifyVars: darkTheme
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you console log `darkTheme` variable which has been imported, all the styling variables are present within `darkTheme.default` object. I have implemented their `aliyum-theme`.

So for you code to work, you need to change `modifyVars` within `config-overrides.js` file to

```js
const { darkTheme } = require('@ant-design/dark-theme');
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports('import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
    style: true,
  }),
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    modifyVars: {...darkTheme.default}
  }),
);
```

ProTip: To override darkTheme within the application, you can create your own javascript file and import it within `config-overrides.js` file and destructure within `modifyVars`

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers weren't working for me. This is what worked for me if it helps anybody else. I *think* it's due to the new less loader version and/or a change in how antd is packaged (I am really not sure).

```js
const { getThemeVariables } = require("antd/dist/theme");
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports("import", {
    libraryName: "antd",
    libraryDirectory: "es",
    style: true,
  }),
  addLessLoader({
    lessOptions: {
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      modifyVars: {
        ...getThemeVariables({
          dark: true,
          compact: true,  // optional
        }),
      },
    },
  })
);
```

Comment: Works with antd 4.15.1, typescript, and webpack 5 

Answer (score 1):

**2023 - Ant Design V5**
A simpler implementation for anyone looking at V5.

This is NextJS not React, but you get the gist:

```
import { ConfigProvider, theme } from 'antd';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import 'antd/dist/reset.css';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        token: {
          // any theme overirdes
          colorPrimary: '#7f00ff',
        },
        // this line sets it to dark mode
        algorithm: theme.darkAlgorithm,
      }}
    >
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
}
```

https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#use-preset-algorithms

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-theme

app.jsx

```
import { Button, Select } from 'antd';
import { ThemeProvider, useTheme } from 'antd-theme';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { SketchPicker } from 'react-color';

const initialTheme = {
  name: 'default',
  variables: { 'primary-color': '#00ff00' },
};

const ThemeSelect = () => {
  const [{ name, variables, themes }, setTheme] = useTheme();

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        style={{ width: 100 }}
        value={name}
        onChange={
          (theme) => setTheme({ name: theme, variables })
        }
      >
        {
          themes.map(
            ({ name }) => (
              <Select.Option key={name} value={name}>
                {name}
              </Select.Option>
            )
          )
        }
      </Select>
      <SketchPicker
        color={variables['primary-color']}
        onChange={(value) => {
          // Will update all css attributes affected by primary-color
          setTheme({ name, variables: { 'primary-color': value.hex } });
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState(initialTheme);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider
      theme={theme}
      onChange={(value) => setTheme(value)}
    >
      <ThemeSelect />
      <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

For those who are using `react-app-rewire-less` and `customize-cra` with react-app-rewired, enable javascript like this

config-overrides.js

```js
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader, addPostcssPlugins, adjustStyleLoaders, addWebpackPlugin } = require('customize-cra');

const AntdThemePlugin = require('antd-theme/plugin');

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports('import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
    style: true,
  }),
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
  }),
  adjustStyleLoaders(
    (loaders) => {
      loaders.use[0] = {
        loader: AntdThemePlugin.loader
      }
    }
  ),
  addWebpackPlugin(
    new AntdThemePlugin({
      themes: [
        {
          name: 'dark',
          filename: require.resolve('antd/lib/style/themes/dark.less'),
        },
        {
          name: 'compact',
          filename: require.resolve('antd/lib/style/themes/compact.less'),
        },
      ],
    })
  ),
);
```